# Rails Minitest / Capybara - adding system integration test for a JS interface element

Tags: capybara, minitest

I have a Rails app that uses this Ion Slider:

https://github.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider

I can test the JS calls that this generates but I figured I would add a system integration test that confirms when the user slides the slider.

To date I have stuck to basic controller tests and very new to Capybara and system integration tests.  I think I can do this but honestly no clue where to start when it comes to a JS interface element like this.

Looking for either an example of a test that would do this or a pointer to the docs that I must have missed in my searching.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Capybara doesn't have a driver independent method to drag an element by a specific amount, but does have a driver independent method for dragging one element onto another (`drag_to`). If that will work for your use case then it would just be something like

```
slider.drag_to(target)
```

If instead you need to just drag by some number of pixels then you will need to use driver dependent code (generally a bad idea, but not really any other option here).  If using the Selenium driver it would be something like

```
action_builder = page.driver.browser.action
action.drag_and_drop_by(slider.native, 100, 0)
```

which should drag the slider element 100 pixels to the right

Below is an example ruby script that demos this behavior, using Chrome, on the ion range slider demo page

```
require 'bundler/inline'

gemfile do
  source 'https://rubygems.org'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'rexml'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
  gem 'byebug'
end

require 'selenium-webdriver'
require "capybara/dsl"
require 'byebug'

%i[selenium_chrome selenium_chrome_headless].each do |driver|
  puts "Using #{driver}"
  sess = Capybara::Session.new(driver)
  sess.visit('http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/demo.html')

  first_demo = sess.first('.demo__item')

  # Capybara driver independent code
  puts "Driver independent:"
  sess.within(first_demo) do
    slider = sess.find('.irs .irs-single')
    slider_max = sess.find('.irs .irs-max')

    initial_text = slider.text
    puts "initial slider text is #{initial_text}"

    slider.drag_to(slider_max) # drag and drop the slider onto the max marker - won't actually be the max value since it drops on the center of the marker

    sess.assert_selector('.irs .irs-single') do |el|
      # example to show one possible way to synchronize with browser
      # will ensure the sliders text has changed
      el.text != initial_text
    end

    puts "new slider text is #{slider.text}"
  end

  # Selenium driver specific code
  puts "Driver specific:"
  sess.within(first_demo) do
    slider = sess.find('.irs .irs-single')
    puts "Current slider text is #{slider.text}"

    action = sess.driver.browser.action # get selenium specific action builder
    action.drag_and_drop_by(slider.native, -100, 0).perform

    puts  "Updated slider text is #{slider.text}"
  end
end
```